# Don't include part of the regex in searched string

Tags: python, regex

I want to use a regex to search a string but not include part of the regex in the returned (or matched) string.

I want to search for and return what occurs after the "CLD: " but don't want the "CLD: " included in the returned (or matched) string.

cloudRegex = re.compile(r'CLD:\s.*')

From the text below I was hoping to return FEW040.

```
FF YBRFYMYX YMMCYMYX YSRFYMYX
061702 YBBNITAS
ATIS YBBN H   061702
RWY: 14
OPR INFO: RUNWAY 19 LEFT AVAILABLE AS PUR NOTAM.  MULTIPLE
TAXIWAY CLOSURES REFER NOTAMS. 
WND: 200/6
VIS: GREATER THAN 10 KM 
CLD: FEW040
+ TMP: 13
+ QNH: 1016
```

Comment: Thanks Wiktor. With the + matching one or more. Will that also work if the is a second word after the "CLD: "? For example, FEW040 SCT050 will be returned from CLD: FEW040 SCT050.

Comment: I decided to remove my comment as I found a thread that is devoted to the same problem, namely get a part of the regex match after a specific keyword. https://ideone.com/pxpeJN should return any text after that `CLD:`

Comment: Just an FYI, I see this all the time. There is no need to not include CLD in the match. Unless you can think of any good reason. Nothing says you have to actually _use group 0_  which is the _match object default return_.  Just get group 1, or 2, or whatever you want. With Python, you don't have any other options than the look behind assertion. This time, `CLD:\s` is fixed length that Python supports. %90 of the time it will be variable length, which Python doesn't support. People reading your title might get hope, but it's no hope, it's just _DOOM_

Answer (score 0):

You can use a **[positive lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)** to achieve this:

```
(?<=CLD:\s).*
```

This will match the string FEW040 in your example, and can be seen working on Regex101 **[here](https://regex101.com/r/3zIKGp/1/)**.